# How does python map works with torch.tensor?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, fast-ai

I am now in python so I am trying to understand this line from [pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nn_tutorial.html).

```
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid = map(
    torch.tensor, (x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid)
)
```

I understand how map works on a single element

```
def sqr(a):
    return a * a

a = [1, 2, 3, 4]    

a = map(sqr, a)
print(list(a))
```

And here I need to use `list(a)` to convert map object back to list.

But what I don't understand, is how does it work on multiple variables?

If I try to do this

```
def sqr(a):
    return a * a


a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 3, 5, 7]

a, b = map(sqr, (a, b))
print(list(a))
print(list(b))
```

I get an error: `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'`

Please clarify this for me
Thank you

Comment: well, you're applying `map` to a tuple of lists.

Comment: you need `a, b = map(sqr, x) for x in (a, b)` for instance

Comment: ah sorry, I read only the end of the question. it works in the other case because the function accepts lists, not single values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`map` works on a single the same way it works on list/tuple of lists, it fetches an element of the given input regardless what is it.

The reason why [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor) works, is that it *accepts* a list as input.

If you unfold the following line you provided:

```
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid = map(
    torch.tensor, (x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid)
)
```

it's the same as doing:

```
x_train, y_train, x_valid, y_valid = [torch.tensor(x_train), torch.tensor(y_train), torch.tensor(x_valid), torch.tensor(y_valid)]
```

On other hand, your `sqr` function does not accept lists. It expects a scalar type to square, which is not the case for your `a` an `b`, they are lists.

However, if you change `sqr` to:

```
def sqr(a):
    return [s * s for s in a]


a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 3, 5, 7]

a, b = map(sqr, (a, b))
```

or as suggested by @Jean, `a, b = map(sqr, x) for x in (a, b)`

It will work.